# Math question probability $P \{|X- E(x)| <3\}$

Tags: probability

We have the probability law of the event X which is

$F(X)= \begin{cases}  4e^{-4x}, & X>=0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

I have to find P|X- E(X)|<3 and then find this again using Tsebisev's inequality..I have already found E(X) and D(X) for this function but I got stuck in this one..how to do it?

EDIT : Since this is the exponential probability function E(X)=1/k and D(X)=1/k^2 so E(X)=1/4 and D(X)=1/16...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$
\begin{align}
P\left(|X-{\rm E}[X]|<\frac34\right)&=P\left(-\frac34<X-\frac14<\frac34\right)\\
&=P\left(-\frac12<X<1\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry,but how do I use that now?

Comment: oh Stefan its P|X- E(X)|<3 not P|X- E(X)|<3/4..

Comment: @sdsdf: You can easily modify my argument to that situation. Also $P(X\in A)=\int_A f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ if $X$ has density function $f$.

Comment: I am thinking about finding D(X)= [E(X)]^2 - E^2(X) ..but how do I relate D(X) to P|X- E(X)|<3?

Comment: You don't. You simply use that $P(a<X<b)=\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ where $f$ is the probability density function (which is $F$ in your notation).

Comment: Oh my god.So in my case P|X- E(X)|<3 I have P(-3<x-1/4<3) so P(-2.75<x<3.25) and I find  the definite integral of 4*e^(-4x) from -2.75 to 3.25.Is it ok now? :D

Comment: and another question : To find D(X) here,just if its asked,can I find it directly since this is an exponential function or do I need to do D(X)=[E(X)]^2 - E^2(X)?

Comment: @sdsdf: No, the density is $0$ for $x<0$, so it's $\int_0^{3.25}\cdots\,\mathrm dx$. You can find the variance however you like: using the definition ${\rm E}[(X-{\rm E}[X])^2]$ or use the formula ${\rm E}[X^2]-{\rm E}[X]^2$.

Comment: Ah thanks.but in this case for the exponential prob. function we have a direct formula which is E(X)=1/k and k in this case is 4..thanks anyway.